# Equivalência de mapeamento entre FluentNHibernate e EntityFrameworkCore?

Tags: entity-framework-core, nhibernate

estou em um projeto onde é necessária a troca do ORM de NHibernate para EntityFrameworkCore. Com isso, todos os mapeamentos terão que ser reescritos para o padrão do Entity e estou tendo algumas dificuldades em refazer as classes.
Será que eu consigo algo na Web que aborde essa transcrição?
Ex: a classe abaixo está escrita em FluentNHibernate:

```
public AgendaGrupoMap()
{
    Table("AGENDA_GRUPO");

    Id(x => x.Id).Column("id_agenda_grupo");

    Map(x => x.IdMedico, "id_medico");
    Map(x => x.IdUnidade, "id_unidade");
    Map(x => x.VigenciaInicio, "dt_vigencia_inicio");
    Map(x => x.VigenciaTermino, "dt_vigencia_termino");
    Map(x => x.Ativo, "fl_ativo");

    HasMany<Agenda>(x => x.Agendas)
        .KeyColumn("id_agenda_grupo")
        .Cascade.None()
        .Not.KeyUpdate();

    References(x => x.Medico)
    .Class<Medico>()
    .Columns("id_medico")
    .Not.Update()
    .Not.Insert();
}
```

e a reescrita para `Entity` está da seguinte forma:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AgendaGrupo> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasColumnName("id_agenda_grupo");

    builder.Property(x => x.IdMedico)
        .HasColumnName("id_medico");

    builder.Property(x => x.IdUnidade)
        .HasColumnName("id_unidade");

    builder.Property(x => x.VigenciaInicio)
        .HasColumnName("dt_vigencia_inicio");

    builder.Property(x => x.VigenciaTermino)
        .HasColumnName("dt_vigencia_termino");

    builder.Property(x => x.Ativo)
        .HasColumnName("fl_ativo");

    builder.HasMany(x => x.Agendas).WithOne(x => x.AgendaGrupo);

    builder.ToTable("AGENDA_GRUPO");
```

Nessa reescrita não sei como reescrever esse trecho (`References`) para o `Entity`:

```
References(x => x.Medico)
    .Class<Medico>()
    .Columns("id_medico")
    .Not.Update()
    .Not.Insert();
```

Vocês podem me sugerir algo? Grato...

Comment: E ai esclareceu a resposta alguma coisa, te ajudou?

Answer (score 0):

De `Nhibernate Map`:

```
References(x => x.Medico)
    .Class<Medico>()
    .Columns("id_medico")
    .Not.Update()
    .Not.Insert();
```

para `Entity Framework Core`

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Medico)
    .WithMany(c => c.AgendaGrupo)
    .HasForeignKey("id_medico");
```

Claro que eu transferi um trecho de código de um para o outro, mas, no site do Microsoft [tem a documentação completa principalmente nessa parte de relacionamentos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Um exemplo de 1 para muitos:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EFModeling.FluentAPI.Relationships.NoForeignKey
{
    #region Model
    class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
                .WithMany(b => b.Posts);
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fluent-api</sup>

Vou dar uma ***dica primordial***, a parte de relacionamento do `Nhibernate` é diferente em relação ao que `Entity Framework` (tanto *Core* e *v.6*) sendo que as chaves de relação:

```
public int PostId { get; set; } 
public Post Post { get; set; }
```

por exemplo no `Entity Framework` são expostas e no `Nhibernate` não, ou seja, respectivamente um é explicito e o outro é implícito, fora que se não colocar tem [a convenção que por padrão coloca o nome dos campos e cria nas tabelas ou dá erro pela falta desses campos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relationships#conventions), melhor configurar tudo.